# how do I create a string of serial data only when the serial port is high and ends when the line goes low?

Tags: python, string, serial-port, pyserial

I am working on a project for my job and I need it to create a string of data only when the com port is high and ends the string when it goes low, it will then analyze the string and look for key words to make a decision.

So here is the setup.

At work we have a fully automated RAM tester that is connected to a computer via serial line to communicate with the software that came with the RAM tester. When the test begins the RAM is inserted into the RAM tester, the tests starts, and data begins to come over the serial line. data such as the current test that is being run, the RAM modules speed, chip configuration, and a timer that counts up until the test is complete (pass or fail) comes over the serial line. when the test is completed the module is removed, then it is dropped down to a conveyor belt that sorts passed modules from failed modules and the next module is inserted into the tester and the process repeats. In between the time where the test is completed and the module is removed, and the next module is inserted, there is a window of time about 3 seconds where the serial line has no data coming over it. This 3 second window is what I am hoping to use to end the capture of my string of serial data, and let python run its assessments to make its decision. once the string is assessed and the decision is made, the program will discard the string and begin reading from the serial port, capturing the data into another string until the 3 second of downtime on the serial line occurs again, ending the capture of data into a string.It will have to loop around and preform this task infinitely. I have every part of this project set to go besides capturing the string of serial data(which is a HUGE part of my project). I just need help on learning how to use the downtime on the serial to end the string. The reason the string has to end according to the 3 second downtime on the serial line is because the data that comes over the serial line for each module varies with the length of the test, ruling out setting a preset number of bytes to read and place into the string. The amount of data varies per module because of the timer. I will include a sample of the serial data on the bottom of my question description, and you can see what I'm talking about when I mention the timer. the higher the capacity of the module, the longer the test takes, and the higher the timer counts which makes the serial data per module higher. Also if the module fails the test ends immediately, so the timer data that comes over the serial line can also be very short. I hope this makes sense since I do not feel that I am the best at explaining things.

Thank you very much for your help in advance!

Here is the sample of the data coming over the serial line I mentioned earlier.

> Åó.þÅþ@.Åþ. ..Waiting for Handler Start ....Åþ....[ Esc. ]Åþe.ÅþE.ÅþE.Åþ.*..L001: wk_addr                    [00:00]Åþ....[Cancel]ÅþA'Åþ.*..L001: wk_data                    [00:00]Åþ....[Cancel]ÅþA'Åþ.*..L001: Mats                       [00:01]Åþ....[Cancel]ÅþA'Åþ...![00:02]Åþ...![00:02]Åþ...![00:03]Åþ...![00:03]Åþ...![00:03]Åþ...![00:04]Åþ...![00:05]Åþ...![00:05]Åþ...![00:06]Åþ...![00:06]Åþ...![00:07]Åþ...![00:07]Åþ...![00:08]Åþ...![00:09]Åþ...![00:09]Åþ...![00:10]Åþ.*..L001: Mar_X                      [00:10]Åþ....[Cancel]ÅþA'Åþ...![00:11]Åþ...![00:11]Åþ...![00:12]Åþ...![00:12]Åþ...![00:12]Åþ...![00:13]Åþ...![00:14]Åþ...![00:14]Åþ...![00:15]Åþ...![00:15]Åþ...![00:16]Åþ...![00:16]Åþ...![00:17]Åþ...![00:18]Åþ...![00:18]Åþ...![00:19]Åþ...![00:19]Åþ...![00:20]Åþ...![00:20]Åþ...![00:21]Åþ.*..L001: Mar_C                      [00:21]Åþ....[Cancel]ÅþA'Åþ...![00:22]Åþ...![00:22]Åþ...![00:23]Åþ...![00:23]Åþ...![00:24]Åþ...![00:24]Åþ...![00:25]Åþ...![00:25]Åþ...![00:26]Åþ...![00:26]Åþ...![00:27]Åþ...![00:28]Åþ...![00:28]Åþ...![00:29]Åþ...![00:29]Åþ...![00:30]Åþ...![00:31]Åþ...![00:31]Åþ...![00:32]Åþ...![00:32]Åþ...![00:32]Åþ...![00:33]Åþ...![00:34]Åþ...![00:34]Åþ...![00:35]Åþ...![00:35]Åþ...![00:36]Åþ...![00:37]Åþ...![00:37]Åþ...![00:37]Åþ...![00:38]Åþ...![00:39]Åþ.*..L001: Mar_Y                      [00:39]Åþ....[Cancel]ÅþA'Åþ...![00:39]Åþ...![00:40]Åþ...![00:40]Åþ...![00:41]Åþ...![00:41]Åþ...![00:42]Åþ...![00:42]Åþ...![00:43]Åþ...![00:43]Åþ...![00:44]Åþ...![00:44]Åþ...![00:45]Åþ...![00:45]Åþ...![00:46]Åþ...![00:46]Åþ...![00:47]Åþ...![00:47]Åþ...![00:48]Åþ...![00:48]Åþ...![00:49]Åþ...![00:49]Åþ...![00:50]Åþ...![00:50]Åþ...![00:51]Åþ...![00:51]Åþ...![00:52]Åþ...![00:52]Åþ...![00:53]Åþe.Åþ}...ÅþE.Åþa¡ÅþD.Åþ"0.Module..: DDR2 256Mx72 2GB 2R(8)@2x400MHZ 1.8V.Åþ"...(Tested at 2x400MHz).Åþ".Addr.(rowxcol.).: 14 x 10.Åþ".Data (rankxbit).:  2 x 72.Åþ".Internal Banks.:  8.Åþ""Burst.: Mode=Sequential, Length=8.Åþ"*AC parameters.: CL=5, AL=0, Trcd=5, Trp=5.Åþ".S/N from SPD.: a128f4f3.Åþ".Test Loop #.: 1.Åþ"..## PASS:   Loop 1 ##.Åþ"..Elapsed Time.: 00:00:53.448.Åþa¢Åþc.............H..ÿÿÿÿ"ÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿ...s-(U.?€.....".. Åþ@.ÅþE.Åþ....**PASS - L001 @2x400MHZÅþ...![00:53]Åþ....Transmit Results ...Åþa¡ÅþD.Åþ"0.Module..: DDR2 256Mx72 2GB 2R(8)@2x400MHZ 1.8V.Åþ"...(Tested at 2x400MHz).Åþ".Addr.(rowxcol.).: 14 x 10.Åþ".Data (rankxbit).:  2 x 72.Åþ".Internal Banks.:  8.Åþ""Burst.: Mode=Sequential, Length=8.Åþ"*AC parameters.: CL=5, AL=0, Trcd=5, Trp=5.Åþ".S/N from SPD.: .Åþ".Test Loop #.: 1.Åþ"..## PASS:   Loop 1 ##.Åþ"..Elapsed Time.: 00:00:53.448.Åþa¢Åþ@.Åþ. ..

This is where the test ends, the module is ejected, another is inserted, and the data starts coming over the serial line again.

Comment: What do you mean by "when the com port is high"? Does the RAM tester use the DCD line to indicate that it is running a test? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RS-232#Signals

Comment: @PeterGibson I&#39;m sorry, was referring to the line as high only when data is coming over it. is there a way I can see if it uses the DCD line? Also, I have done some looking around and I think I found some software that will redirect the serial port's data to a virtual serial port and inject a emulated DCD signal if it is needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you want to keep reading characters from the serial port until there is a gap of no characters for some time period, then process that data. Try something like (note, this is untested):

```
buf = ''
ser.timeout = 1
while True:
    data = ser.read() # read a single character
    buf += data
    if data == '': # emtpy string indicates a read timeout
        processs_data(buf)
        buf = '' # wipe the buffer
```

Comment: awsome, that looks like it should work. I never thought to try somthing like the buf += data part. I appreciate you help very much. would you happen to have any idea how I would get somthing like this to loop around infinitely?

Comment: @RollyAponte the above code will already loop due to the `while True` statement

Comment: Ok, won't it not be true once I hit the 3 second down time and end the loop?  ( sorry I would just try it out and troubleshoot  but I can only work on this for a small amount of time at work so I want to make it as functional as possible before I get to work)

Comment: @RollyAponte No, a `while` loop keeps going until the expression after it evaluates to `False` (in this case that never happens as I've explicitly set it to `True`), or until you manually `break` out of the loop. See http://www.pythonforbeginners.com/control-flow-2/python-for-and-while-loops

Comment: alright I see, I have used While loops when working with Arduino i guess I'm just getting caught up on the  if data = '': part. so if data = '' its not a false?

Comment: `if data == ''` will evaluate to false when some data was returned by the read method, but this only affects the `if` statement, not the outer loop. (Note I've just fixed a typo there, it should have a double equal sign for the comparison, not a single equal sign).

Comment: well I think everything should be working on the python side. I wasn't able to test it today since the RAM tester was in use all day with no downtime.  now it's time to start working on the arduino side of things. you have been extremely helpful and just want to thank you once again for being patient and giving me a hand with this.

Comment: @RollyAponte No worries :) Good luck with the rest